# Does "the way around" means the same thing as "the opposite"?

Tags: meaning

A talks with B, A says, the universe revolves around the earth. B says, no,it is the way around.
Is this use of "the way around" comprehensible, just meaning the same as "it is the opposite"?

Answer (score 4):

While I largely agree with Zibbobz' analysis (the intended phrase is *the other way around* and it is a specific format of creating an "opposite"-style statement), I think the usage of *the other way around* is restricted to cases where there is a statement of the general form "X (has some relationship to) Y"; when you say "no, it's the other way around" you are asserting that in fact the statement should be "Y (has some relationship to) X."

In the original example, Person A has stated that X is "the universe", the relationship is "revolves around", and Y is "the earth".  Person B counters that instead of "X -> Y", it should be "Y -> X", so B's assertion is that "The earth revolves around the universe".

You can use this in a variety of situations, such as

> We went to the store and then the movie.  Wait, it was the other way around; we went to the movie and then the store.
>
> Did the first chicken create the first egg, or was it the other way around?

You would not say "no, it's the other way around" in response to "make a right turn" because there's no X and Y to be reversed in that statement.

Comment: Err, except the Earth does not, in fact, revolve around the universe. :-)

Comment: Hey, it's not my fault if A and B are both stupid.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are thinking of the phrase "[the other way around](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/the+other+way+around)", which does essentially mean "the opposite", but in a specific way.

The specific nature of "the other way around" is that it means that doing what you say in the opposite *direction* is correct, not necessarily the exact opposite.

As an example, if someone erroniously told you to go right, you could say "no, it's the other way around", which would mean going left.  But if someone were to tell you that the correct color to pick on a quiz show is white, when it is really black, you could not say "no, it's the other way around", because although black is the opposite of white, it is not in 'the other direction'.

In your case, the direction is actually the way in which the phrase is said.  So rather than "the universe revolves around the earth", person B is saying it is "the other way around", that "the earth revolves around the universe".

"The way around" is not the correct way to phrase this.  I suspect you may have heard it incorrectly, or seen it written incorrectly.

You might also hear it referred to as "the [other way round](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/other+way+round)", with the understanding that 'round' is a slightly shorter way of saying 'around'.